# Android - Black Frame after dismissing Progress Dialog

Tags: progressdialog, android

After dismissing a Progress Dialog there's a black frame that fills the screen and disappears after a second, any idea why this is happening and how to solve it ?

Comment: Are you sure you aren't calling dismiss from a background thread?

Comment: We may need some more details/code.

Comment: @KevinM Yes I am! thanks for pointing that, I'll test the code asap and post the answer here.